# How to reset background color of UICollectionVIewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a keyboard(for a to z letter) using UICollectionView, I am able to highlight the letter which the user has pressed. Now I want the all highlighted cell should reset as user click on next button

I try to reset the background cell color, for this, I created a function as I created for highlight the tapped UICollectionViewCell

Calling this function in didSelectItemAt

```
 func keyboardTappedCellColor(cell: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell: UICollectionViewCell = keyboardCollectionView.cellForItem(at: cell)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
    selectedCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Calling this function in cellForItemAt, as a user will click on the next button reloading the UICollectionView. Getting app crashed here
 I am not sure this is the right process or not.

```
    func resetKeyboardCellTappedColor(cell: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: UICollectionViewCell = keyboardCollectionView.cellForItem(at: cell)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    selectedCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

I want how many cells tapped in UICollectionViewCell it should change its background and user-interaction should be disabled for tapped cell, and as user click on next button it should reset the highlighted and enable the user user-interaction

Comment: Why you are reloading collectionView?  you have resettled the cell i dont think so there is any need to reload collection on pressing next button.

Comment: also your question is too ambiguous as it dont tell if you want a solution to crash or if just suggestion for proper code. 
If you want a solution to code please attach crash report  too.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan so how can i reset the background color as user click on next button

Comment: When you are calling this method? resetKeyboardCellTappedColor

Comment: @AbuUlHassan i need to call resetKeyboardCellTappedColor as i click on Next button, where is the right place to call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are allowing multiple selections in your collectionView like this 
`collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`

To Select / Deselect cell you can override the UICollectionViewCell property `isSelected`

```
 override var isSelected: Bool{

    didSet{
        self.backgroundColor = isSelected ? SELECTEDCOLOR: UNSELECTEDCOLOR

    }
}
```

> To Get the selected Cell indexes :

```
let selectedItems = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
```

> To Reset the Selected cell:

```
 for indexPath in selectedItems {
     self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated:true)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In you custom `UICollectionViewCell`, you simply need to override **`isSelected`** property with the relevant code in its `didSet` and nothing else is needed.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
        }
    }

    //rest of the code...
}
```

Cell selection and other cells' deselection will be handled automatically.